# Diet ubuntu for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

The [Diet Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Diet%20Ubuntu) article on ubuntu wiki lists package names that are useful potential candidates for "bloatware" for some users that want remove some packages. But this article was written in 2008 and last updated in 2011.

Is there a more recent list of this kind for ubuntu 12.04?

**edit** it would be good if one could keep his running system. installing a new one is not what I seek for, at least. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD.

Even though the article you read wasn't up-to-date, the link they gave for the MinimalCD is kept up. They currently have 8.04 Hardy Heron through 13.04 Raring Ringtail in there, ready as a Minimal ISOs.

This list includes x32 and x64 architectures along with 32bit and 64bit PowerPC ones. For two versions (8.04 and 10.04, both LTS) it supports stranger ones such as Itanium and Sparc (whatever those are)

Comment: thanks! I would like to avoid installing a new system though. it's already quite customized because there is a custom development environment on it. As I do not wish to break things I just try to uninstall some packages.

Comment: I see. I don't know of any such lists off the top of my head, but if I find one I will tell you. In the meantime, you can try googling what programs are needed for Ubuntu/other programs you _want_ to use depend on. If one you _don't_ want isn't listed anywhere and nothing warns you about anything during the uninstallation of the package, go ahead and uninstall it.

Comment: IMO , because of dependencies, it is much much easier to start with a minimal install and build up rather then to start to remove things, more so if you are unfamiliar with a minimal install. Everyone has a different list of what they consider minimal , lol

Comment: @bodhi.zazen true. still it is always interesting for me to read *others'* list of what *they* find 'minimal'. I don't know why, but maybe because I like reading about other people's commons and because I don't know the normal install in-out enough anyway, so for me it's informative. It's a luxury to have a 'Diet' list rather than a requirement (or goal), in this sense.